# Is there a quick way to convert a .ive file to a .dae file?

Tags: collada, openscenegraph

I'm looking for a way to convert a `.ive` file to `.dae`.
I already tried using the `osgconv` in 3.0.1 and failed.

Answer (score 0):

What failed in osgconv?  Do you just not have the collada plugin?  Was there an error message?  The collada plugin might not be in your build if you don't have the right dependencies.

Try just grabbing some older prebuilt osg binaries, eg:
https://github.com/rpavlik/osg-windows-binaries

or
http://openscenegraph.alphapixel.com/osg/downloads/free-openscenegraph-binary-downloads

And you should be able to use osgConv.

Of course, the other thing you could do is convert it to some other intermediate file type that can be opened by whatever modeling program you can find (Wings3D, Sketchup, Blender come to mind), and use those to export DAE.